# Group children objects to JSON array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am having 2 datasets:

1. User

```
Id, Name
1, Jack
2, Jill
3, James
```

2. Activities

```
Id, Activity, UserId
101, Activity 1, 1
102, Activity 2, 1
201, Activity 3, 2
301, Activity 4, 3
```

How can I use PySpark to add a column named "Activities" to the User dataset, which groups all activities related to an user in JSON format. The expecting output is:

```
Id, Name, Activities
1, Jack, [{Id: 101, Name: Activity 1}, {Id: 102, Name: Activity 2}]
2, Jill, [{Id: 201, Name: Activity 3}]
3, James, [{Id: 301: Name: Activity 4}]
```

Comment: Are you planning to store final table as JSON including ID and NAME column?

Comment: Final table will be Parquet file, the Activities column will have an array of activities.

Answer (score 2):

Having non-json and json data together can be little bit tricky. The solution below creates JSON structure for all columns including ID and Name, so its close approximation of final result ..

first , Lets create sample data -

```
list1 = [1,"Jack"],[2,"Jill"],[3,"James"]
df1=spark.createDataFrame(list1,schema=["id","Name"])

list2= [101,"Activity1",1],[101,"Activity2",1],[201,"Activity3",2],[301,"Activity4",3]
df2=spark.createDataFrame(list2,schema=['Id','Activity','UserId'])
```

then register both dataframes as temporary tables, so we can execute sql on it to format the data the way we want -

```
df1.registerTempTable("table1")
df2.registerTempTable("table2")
```

Then run a sql which uses combination of `collect_list` and `named_struct` to closely match your final structural requirements

```
df3= spark.sql("""
    WITH tmp 
     AS (SELECT t1.id, 
                Collect_list(Named_struct("id", t2.id, "name", t2.activity)) AS 
                   Activities 
         FROM   table1 t1 
                JOIN table2 t2 
                  ON ( t1.id = t2.userid ) 
         GROUP  BY t1.id) 
    SELECT tmp.id, 
           t3.NAME, 
           tmp.activities 
    FROM   tmp 
           JOIN table1 t3 
             ON ( tmp.id = t3.id ) 
        """)

df3.toJSON().collect()
```

this gives me result as -

```
['{"id":1,"NAME":"Jack","activities":[{"id":101,"name":"Activity1"},{"id":101,"name":"Activity2"}]}',
 '{"id":3,"NAME":"James","activities":[{"id":301,"name":"Activity4"}]}',
 '{"id":2,"NAME":"Jill","activities":[{"id":201,"name":"Activity3"}]}']
```

if I remove `toJSON()` transformations and simply show result,  it shows as

```
 df3.show() 


+---+-----+-----------------------------------+
| id| NAME|          activities               |
+---+-----+-----------------------------------+
|  1| Jack|[[101, Activity1],[101, Activity2]]|
|  3|James|  [[301, Activity4]]               |
|  2| Jill|  [[201, Activity3]]               |
+---+-----+-----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have two dataframe dfUser and dfActivities

```py
joinDf=   dfUser.join(dfActivities, col('Id')==col('UserId'))
                .withColumnRenamed(dfActivities['Id'], "aId") 
                .groupBy(col("Id"))
                .agg(collect_list("aId","Activity").alias("Activities"))
```